# scrapear varias subpaginas

Tags: python, scraping

creo que llevo bastante avanzado el 'for', pero sólo me imprime el último resultado, espero que sólo sea una tontería que se me está pasando por alto.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from tqdm import tqdm

# lista de partidos del día elegido

url = 'https://es.besoccer.com/livescore/2022-09-16'
matches = requests.get(url)

s_matches = BeautifulSoup(matches.text, 'lxml')

links = s_matches.find('div', attrs={'class':'matches'}).select('a[href*="/partido/"]')
links

link = links[0]
link

link_match = [link.get('href') for link in links]
link_match  # Hasta aquí hemos recibido la lista

# Hacemos un 'for' para que busque analisis en la lista de partidos. 
# La palabra ("variable") que se pone detrás guarda cada registro de la lista y va haciendo un bucle

for url_match in link_match:
    try:
        r_analisis = requests.get(url_match)
        if r_analisis.status_code == 200:
            s_analisis = BeautifulSoup(r_analisis.text, 'lxml')
            find_analisis = s_analisis.find('div', attrs={'class':'menu-scroll'}).select('a[href*="analisis"]')
            analisis = find_analisis[0]
            link_analisis = analisis.get('href')
            r_link_analisis = requests.get(link_analisis)
            s_link_analisis = BeautifulSoup(r_link_analisis.text, 'lxml') 

            def obtener_stats(s_link_analisis):
                stats_dict = {}
                
                date = s_link_analisis.find('div', attrs={'starttime':'info match-link'})
                if date:
                    stats_dict['date'] = date.get_text('/', strip=True)
                else:
                    stats_dict['date'] = None 

                time = s_link_analisis.find('div', attrs={'class':'data'})
                if time:
                    stats_dict['time'] = time.get_text('/', strip=True)
                else:
                    stats_dict['time'] = None

                competition = s_link_analisis.find('h3', attrs={'class':'competition'})
                if competition:
                    stats_dict['competition'] = competition.get_text('/', strip=True)
                else:
                    stats_dict['competition'] = None

                homeTeam = s_link_analisis.find('p', attrs={'itemprop':'homeTeam'})
                if homeTeam:
                    stats_dict['homeTeam'] = homeTeam.get_text('/', strip=True)
                else:
                    stats_dict['homeTeam'] = None

                homeRank = s_link_analisis.find('div', attrs={'class':'position t1'})
                if homeRank:
                    stats_dict['homeRank'] = homeRank.get_text()
                else:
                    stats_dict['homeRank'] = None    

                homeGoals = s_link_analisis.find('div', attrs={'class':'content-box t-1'}).find('div', attrs={'class':'poss-box'})
                if homeGoals:
                    stats_dict['homeGoals'] = homeGoals.get_text('/', strip=True)
                else:
                    stats_dict['homeGoals'] = None     

                awayTeam = s_link_analisis.find('p', attrs={'itemprop':'awayTeam'})
                if awayTeam:
                    stats_dict['awayTeam'] = awayTeam.get_text('/', strip=True)
                else:
                    stats_dict['awayTeam'] = None     

                awayRank = s_link_analisis.find('div', attrs={'class':'position t2'})
                if awayRank:
                    stats_dict['awayRank'] = awayRank.get_text()
                else:
                    stats_dict['awayRank'] = None     

                awayGoals = s_link_analisis.find('div', attrs={'class':'content-box t-2'}).find('div', attrs={'class':'poss-box'})
                if awayGoals:
                    stats_dict['awayGoals'] = awayGoals.get_text('/', strip=True)
                else:
                    stats_dict['awayGoals'] = None     

                draw = s_link_analisis.find('div', attrs={'class':'content-box draw'}).find('div', attrs={'class':'cont'})
                if draw:
                    stats_dict['draw'] = draw.get_text('/', strip=True)
                else:
                    stats_dict['draw'] = None    

                return stats_dict

        else:
            print('1.- No se pudo obtener la página de análisis', url_match)
    
    except:
        print('2.- No se pudo obtener la página de análisis', url_match)
        
    
obtener_stats(s_link_analisis)

df = pd.DataFrame(obtener_stats(s_link_analisis), index=list(range(0,50)))

df.head()
```

---

Estoy scrapeando una web de estadísticas de partidos de futbol, en la página con los partidos diarios puedo scrapear todas las url de los partidos de cada día, ahora necesito añadirle a la url la terminación "/analisis" porque ahí es donde se encuentran las estadísticas, y después scrapear dicha web de estadísticas de cada uno de los partidos.

Lo primero, cómo puedo añadir esa terminación a cada una de las url que he conseguido?
Y después, cómo hago para scrapear una lista? he leído varios artículos y visto varios videos pero a mi no me funciona nada

Este es mi código:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from tqdm import tqdm

url = 'https://es.besoccer.com/livescore/2022-09-15'
besoccer = requests.get(url)

besoccer.status_code

bs_soup = BeautifulSoup(besoccer.text, 'lxml')

type(bs_soup)

print(bs_soup.prettify())

links = bs_soup.find('div', attrs={'class':'matches'}).find_all('a')
links

link_match = [link.get('href') for link in links]
link_match
```

Muchas gracias de antemano

---

Comment: Si sabes como scrapear una página, pon el código en una función que reciba la URL y extraiga la información. Si tienes una lista de páginas, iteras sobre ella llamando a la función en cada pasada.

Comment: en eso de "iterar" sobre ella es donde me pierdo

Comment: Bueno, tienes una lista. Haces un `for url in lista: scrapear(url)`

Comment: ok, voy a probar, gracias

Comment: nada, no se cómo hacerlo,     :(

Comment: Mmmmm, una url en este caso no es mas que una cadena. Busca "formatear cadena python" en google y te encontraras varias formas de crear una nueva cadena a partir de otras. Y lo otro, tenes una lista, y podes recorrer cada item de una lista con un bucle for (ej: for item in lista). Esto es lo que te dijeron antes.

Comment: gracias amigo, y si quiero seleccionar sólo las url que contengan la palabra "partido", lo puedo hacer con "select()", o cómo sería lo correcto? gracias

Comment: ya lo encontré!!!!!! heheheh

```
soup.select('a[href*="partido"]')
```

al poner el href* y después la cadena de búsqueda le estás indicando que selecciones sólo las url que contengan la palabra que estás buscando, muchas gracias

Comment: ahora toca seguir peleandome con el for, porque realmente no soy capaz de entender cómo hacer el for y meter dentro el scraping 
seguiré informando, jejejej
gracias a todos

Comment: hola amigos, creo que llevo bastante avanzado el 'for', pero sólo me imprime el último resultado, espero que sólo sea una tontería que se me está pasando por alto.

Comment: hola @CandidMoe , creo que he avanzado un poco con el 'for' pero me muestra siempre únicamente el último resultado, a ver si podéis echarle un vistazo al código y veis en lo que estoy fallando

muchas gracias